# Which Linux platfrom required for Installation of ingres database version 9.2 and openROAD version 4.0

Tags: ingres

Hi I need to install  ingres database version 9.2 and openROAD version 4.0. on a linux based system.

Please provide me reference site or instructions to install.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want answers don't use Stackoverflow as its ridiculous policies prevent me supplying the four links that would have been helpful to you.  Google for the Actian community, which you will find far more helpful with fewer egos struggling to rule the world.